# Getting rid of sex drive

Tags: sex, breaking-habits, libido, male

What are the options for a young healthy man to get rid of sex drive for good?

I think the desire for sex is a weakness, a chain in the neck, and enemy of a focused mind. I want to get rid of this desire for good. This should release a lot of time and attention to more enduring pleasures.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castration